# How to set up Windows to use a network Desktop directory upon logging into a network

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, login

I want to set up a file server for a Windows network so that the each Windows 7 client will automatically set its Desktop, Documents, directories to each user's home directory on the network (much like a RHEL network), and not have a local Desktop directory.

Is it possible to set up a server and Windows 7 workstations for this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look into "folder redirection."  This page has some pretty good info:  [How To Configure Folder Redirection](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/performance/configure-folder-redirection.html)

All clients, and the file server, need to be part of the same Active Directory domain, and you need to have permissions to be able to setup a group policy object to roll out the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done automatically, you would want to use group policy to do it. This requires Active Directory, not sure if you have that set up or if you are able to.  You can also do it locally on each computer, but the only way to make it automatically happen for all workstations is with GPOs via Active Directory.